# I want to set an arbitrary key:value property on a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

For my iOS program, I want to set an arbitrary key:value property on a UIView. I couldn't find any way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Try answering his question insetad of downvoting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Layers are key-value compliant, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/400251/264619 (go upvote that answer), so you could set key:values on a view's layers instead.

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[myView.layer setValue: @"hello" forKey: @"world"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Attach an `NSMutableDictionary` to the `UIView` using `objc_setAssociatedObject`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html

Comment: on iOS, one can't use the Objective-C runtime functions directly.

Comment: working doesn't mean you can use it. Headers and libs are available but their use is prohibited.

Comment: Link to any documentation of this claim?

Comment: BTW Apple's [Recipes and Printing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Recipes_+_Printing/Listings/Classes_RecipePrintPageRenderer_m.html) sample code uses `objc_setAssociatedObject`.

Comment: Of course you can use the Obj-C runtime functions! I have multiple apps in app store that use this. You just have to import the runtime header: #import <objc/runtime.h>

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is to use the receiver's memory address as a key in a dictionary, and set 
subsequent, embedded ditionaries for those keys:

```
#define KEY(o) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", o]

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])
    {
        // other stuff
        NSMutableDictionary *globalKeys = [NSMutableDictionary new]; // don't forget to release in dealloc
    }
    return self;
}

// and where you want to set a key-value pair:
- (void) addKey:(NSString *)key value:(id)value forObject:(id)obj
{
    NSString *objKey = KEY(obj);
    NSDictionary *objDict = [globalKeys objectForKey:objKey];
    if (!objDict)
    {
        [globalKeys setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKey:objKey];
    }
    [objDict setValue:value forKey:key];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of something like this if there wasn't a way to actuall add the properties to the view itself.